# python sklearn KDTree with haversine distance

Tags: python, scikit-learn, kdtree

I try to create a KD tree of WGS84 coordinates and find neighbors within a certain radius

```
from sklearn.neighbors.dist_metrics import DistanceMetric
from sklearn.neighbors.kd_tree import KDTree    
T = KDTree([[47.8665, 8.90123]], metric=DistanceMetric.get_metric('haversine'))
```

But get the following error:

```
ValueError: metric HaversineDistance is not valid for KDTree
```

How can I use haversine distance in a KD-Tree?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The k-d-tree can (to the best of my knowledge) only be used with Minkowski norms.

There are other trees such as the ball tree in sklearn, or the covertree in ELKI that work with Haversine distance because it is a metric.

Comment: You can also use the KDTree but then you have to convert your longitude, latitude pairs to carthesian/euclidean values and convert the distance value back to miles or kilometers than. As far as I know you can also convert longitude and latitude to radians which gives you the distances directly in kilometers. But haven't tested that.

Comment: @Matthias: That doesn't work for large distances, though. Points `[0km, 40 000km]` and `[0km, -40 000km]` are very close to each other on a globe, but not according to the KDTree you propose.

Answer (score 0):

`KDTree.valid_metrics`

Output -

```
['p',
 'l1',
 'chebyshev',
 'manhattan',
 'minkowski',
 'cityblock',
 'l2',
 'euclidean',
 'infinity']
```

Which tells, you can't use `haversine` with KDTree. The reason behind it is `haversine` distance gives you [Orthodromic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance) distance which is the distance measure used when your points are represented in a sphere. But in a kdTree the points are organised in a tree which makes it invalid to use.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Any idea to how to make it run faster than in O(n^2) (calculating all distance pairs) ?

Comment: There are trees which work with haversine. But the kd-tree doesn't. In python, the ball-tree is an example.

Comment: Oh I was totally unaware of that. Thanks for the info. I'll read about it.